# Magento 2: How to get system.xml config values?

Tags: magento2, configuration

I am trying to create a custom system configuration but I am having trouble getting the values.

I created a simple module like in this [tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/). So: 
 
`app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

`app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mageplaza_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
?>
```

`app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="mageplaza" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Then is followed this [tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html) to create the system config:
`app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="mageplaza" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Mageplaza</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="helloworld" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Hello World</label>
            <tab>mageplaza</tab>
            <resource>Mageplaza_HelloWorld::hello_configuration</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

`app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <helloworld>
            <general>
                <enable>1</enable>
                <display_text>Hello World</display_text>
            </general>
        </helloworld>
    </default>
</config>
```

`Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $objectManager;

    const XML_PATH_HELLOWORLD = 'helloworld/';



    public function __construct(Context $context,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->storeManager  = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
        );
    }


    public function getGeneralConfig($code, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_HELLOWORLD . $code, $storeId);
    }


}
```

I can see the config but when I try to request the values like this:

```
$helper = $this->objectManager->create('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data');
echo $helper->getGeneralConfig('enable');
echo $helper->getGeneralConfig('display_text');
```

I get an error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property: Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Display\Interceptor::$objectManager
```

Comment: try $helper = $this->objectManager->get('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to inject `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface` into `Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Display` before use it. Like this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
) {
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

P/S: If your class is a controller extends `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` class, you don't need to inject `ObjectManagerInterface`, use directly

```
$helper = $this->_objectManager->create('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data');
```

Comment: Thank you! `$helper = $this->_objectManager->create('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data');` this worked!

Comment: _Magento prohibits the direct use of the ObjectManager in your code because it hides the real dependencies of a class._

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * scope config 
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig 
) { 
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}  

$config_val =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('section/group/field', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```